# Is there any easy way to see that elementary matrices commute in $\text {Mat}_{n \times n} (\mathbb F)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any easy way to see that elementary matrices commute in $\text {Mat}_{n \times n} (\mathbb F)$ ?

I've been trying to sketch a proof by induction, but it seems more complicated that it should be.

Induction start is easy by considering $1 \times 1$, but in general there are many cases ?

Def: An elementary matrix is an $n \times n$-matrix corresponding to an elementary row operation.

Comment: What is your definition of elementary matrices?

Comment: Don't 'elementary matrices' usually include transpositions? (i.e., matrices $E$ such that $EA = A'$ has the same rows as $A$, but with two of them swapped)?  If so, then they don't in general commute. So proving this will be really tough!

Comment: An elementary matrix is an $n \times n$-matrix corresponding to an elementary row operation.

Comment: Another argument why this isn't so. Each nondegenerate matrix is a product of elementary matrices. If elementary matrices commuted, *all* nondegenerate matrices would commute! This would be way too good to be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't, because they don't (for $n>1$).

Every invertible matrix is a product of elementary matrices. If invertible matrices commuted, then any two invertible matrices would commute!

Can you find an example of two elementary matrices which don't commute?

Comment: You mean, a product of *elementary* matrices?

Comment: @Ihf Yes, thanks ;). Just woke up. At least it was technically correct!

Comment: Thank you, I see that the elementary matrix corresponding to adding row 1 to row 2 and the elementary matrix corresponding to adding row 2 to row 1 don't commute for $2 \times 2$.